# Trouble With the Definition of $\Delta$-Complex in Hatcher's Book

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition, simplicial-complex

On Pg. 103 of Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology* the author has defined what a $\Delta$-complex is:

This is what I have gathered from what the author writes:

> A $\Delta$-complex is a collection of oriented (geometric) simplices $\mathcal S=\{\Delta_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in J}$ indexed by a set $\alpha$ along with a collection of sets $\{\mathcal F_\beta\}_{\beta\in K}$, where each $\mathcal F_\beta$ is a collection of faces of the simplices in $\mathcal S$ of a common dimension.

This data is purely combinatorial. Given a $\Delta$-complex $\mathcal S=\{\Delta_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in J}$ and $\{\mathcal F_\beta\}_{\beta\in K}$, we may form the quotient space $\bigsqcup_{\alpha\in J} \Delta_{\alpha}/\sim$, where sim identifies the faces in each $\mathcal F_\beta$ via the canonical isomorphism (using the orientation of the faces) between the faces in it.

> Is the above correct? Or have I got the definition wrong?

---

**Here is another trouble**:

On the next page, Hatcher writes the following:

> Since the face identifications that produce a $\Delta$-complex $X$ always preserve the orderings of the vertices, these identifications never result in two distinct points in the interior of a face getting identifies in $X$. (I understand this).
>
> *This means that $X$, as a set, is the disjoint union of a collection of open simplices --- simplices with all their proper faces deleted*.
>
> Each such open simplex $e^n_\alpha$ of dimension $n$ comes equipped with a canonical map $\sigma_\alpha:\Delta^n\to X$ *restricting to a homeomorphism from the interior of $\Delta^n$ onto $e^n_\alpha$*.
>
> **Namely, the closure of $e^n_\alpha$ is the quotient of one of the simplices from which $X$ was constructed, or a face of one of these simplices, and $\sigma_\alpha$ is the quotient map from this simplex or face to $X$**.

I do not understand what the author is trying to say here. I understand the parts in *italics* to some extent while the part in **bold** went completely tangential.

Can somebody write an easier to read definition of a $\Delta$-complex. What is the idea we are trying to capture?

Comment: Do you have an up to date copy of the text, I don't see the quotes in my copy.  It is freely available as a .pdf at http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html

Comment: @Aaron I had recently bought a hard copy from which I quoted these. You are right. The e-copy is different from mine. I guess I will read from the e-copy.